# Limit number of results in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following `Xquery` code:

```
for $w in $words
let $freq := (count($corpus[. eq $w]) div count($content2[text() eq $w])) 
order by $freq descending
return <tr><td>{$w}</td><td>{$freq}</td></tr>
```

`$words` is some distinct words that appears (may appear multiple times) in `$corpus`. `$content2` is some another bag of words. Variables and division is not that important.

This `xquery` lists some frequency calculation of words, ordered.

What I want to do is limit the results by 10.
I tried to use positional values but as it gives me the position of the word in the word list, it didnt work out..

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `subsequence($sequence, $start, $records)` to return a subset of results, starting at record `$start` (be aware XQuery counts from 1) returning `records` items. Have a look at ["Limiting Result Sets" XQuery Wikibooks Page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Limiting_Result_Sets#Sorting_Before_Limiting_Results). An example of how to apply the function copied from this page:

```
let $sorted-people :=
   for $person in collection($collection)/person
   order by $person/last-name/text()
   return $person

for $person at $count in subsequence($sorted-people, $start, $records)
return
   <li>{ $person/last-name/text() }</li>
```

Comment: There are no curly brackets, the right version is `<li>{$person/last-name/text()}</li>`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, at the same time I improved the whole answer, anyway.

Answer (score 17):

The number of results can e.g. be limited as follows:

```
(for $w in $words
 let $freq := (count($corpus[. eq $w]) div count($content2[text() eq $w])) 
 order by $freq descending
 return <tr><td>{$w}</td><td>{$freq}</td></tr>
)[position() = 1 to 10]
```

Comment: This only works with MarkLogic (it’s not part of the official specification).